# JSON parse issue for Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Running this code for Android using eclipse
    I added "bbbbbb" as additional value to check JSON object failed or not in case of incorrect values, but showing me valid JSON, I don't understand what is wrong. This is sample JSON, so I want to create generic code which use for any JSON file

```
//json string - start

{
"alert": [{
"id": "1",
"msg": "TEST 2"
}]
}
bbbbbb

///////////////////////////

try {
            mjson = new JSONObject(json_string);
            ToastMsg("Valid JSON");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            ToastMsg("Invalid JSON" + e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Could be that anything after the last } bracket is ignored in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [JSONTokener.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONTokener.java):

> This parser is lenient. A successful parse does not necessarily
>   indicate that the input string is valid JSON.